# EMR Step command-runner hive-script

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, boto3, emr

I am trying to run a hive-script which is on S3 on an EMR cluster.

When connecting via SSH to the EMR cluster, then typing

```
"hive -f s3://..."
```

works. However, I want this to be done automatically so I created a python script and am trying to add a step to the cluster. However, I can not get this step to run, not even when manually adding it via the AWS Console.
For the jar file, I specify "command-runner.jar" but whatever arguments I then use (i tried it with "hive -f s3://..." as suggested by another thread but that does not work), the step always fails immediately.
When switching to script-runner.jar instead of command-runner, I can get it somehow to work with the command

```
/usr/share/aws/emr/scripts/hive-script --run-hive-script --args -f s3://...
```

However, after a few seconds I get an error and in stderr I will find this error.

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.13.1-amzn-3/lib/hive-common-0.13.1-amzn-3.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:692)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:636)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1420)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2483)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2495)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1418)
... 12 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, username = hive. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'hive'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
```

Ideally, I would want to solve this by using command-runner.jar. Can someone tell me the correct arguments I should use for this (in the aws console and/or in the Boto3 parameter for add_job_flow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for anyone with the same problem: Turned out that I missed adding "Hive" to the applications for the EMR cluster...

Answer (score 0):

Run a hive script from S3

```
hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar hive-script --run-hive-script --args -f  s3://path/scripts/hive_show_table.hql
```